# Amicable number using fuction

Tags: python

I tried to see what is the pair of the amicable number (under 20000).
(amicable number: two different numbers so related that the sum of the proper divisors of each is equal to the other number. (A proper divisor of a number is a positive factor of that number other than the number itself. For example, the proper divisors of 6 are 1, 2, and 3.)
So I wrote codes..and debugged.

```
def amicable(num):
    a=1
    for i in range(2,num):
        if num%i==0:
            a=a+i
    return a
for j in range(2,20000):
    amicable(j)
for k in range(2,20000):
    amicable(k)

if amicable(j)==k and amicable(k)==j and j!=k:
    print(j,'Amicable',k)
```

It works, but it donesn't print anything.
What is the problem?

Comment: Is your code indented properly?  It makes no sense with the posted indentation.  Also, the first two calls to `amicable` serve no purpose.  You call it, it returns a value, and you discard it.  You might as well delete those calls.

Comment: Oh I solved the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code, except `amicable` function, shuold be changed logically and also syntactically.

- You perform many function calls without a purpose:

  ```
  for j in range(2,20000):
      amicable(j)  # This call returns integer value, but result of this call is not used anywhere
  for k in range(2,20000):
      amicable(k)  # Same as above
  ```
- if-statement is logically correct but syntactically not. You have a typo `amicalbe(k)==j` -> `amicable(k)==j`
- You want to check all combinations of pairs of numbers `j` and `k`, so you must perform if-statement for *each pair* of numbers `j` and `k`:

  ```
  for j in range(2,20000):
      for k in range(2,20000):
          if amicable(j)==k and amicable(k)==j and j!=k:
              print(j,'Amicable',k)  # prints for ex. 220 Amicable 284
  ```

  What you have done previously, was to perform if-statement only for "lastly assigned" values of `j` and `k`, because after execution of for-loop iterator-variable has its "lastly assigned" value:

  ```
  for value in range(2, 20000):
      pass
  print(value)  # prints "lastly assigned" value: 19999
  ```